# Passing UTF-8 text to php script

Tags: php, objective-c, utf-8, network-protocols, nsurlrequest

Hullo,
I would allow people to enter in my application also text with non latin characters, like cyrillic and the kind. Still, whatever I do question marks appear instead.
This is the code I have on my objective-c program:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/iPhone/php/insert.php?recipientEmail=%@&passwd=%@&email=%@&personalPasswd=%@&private=%d&latitude=%f&longitude=%f&altitude=%f&horizontal=%f&vertical=%f&disclosedEmail=%d", appDelegate.actualHttpHeader, myRecipient, myKey, email, passwd, myPrivate?1:0, myLatitude, myLongitude, myAltitude, myHeading, myTilting, mySigning?1:0]]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy                                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    //NSLog(@"message is:%@",myMessage);
    //myMessage = [myMessage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"in graffitiSubm message=%@", myMessage);
    [theRequest addValue:myMessage forHTTPHeaderField:@"message"];
    [theRequest addValue:street forHTTPHeaderField:@"street"];
    [theRequest addValue:city forHTTPHeaderField:@"city"];
    [theRequest addValue:country forHTTPHeaderField:@"country"];
    [theRequest setValue: @"text/xml;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

I tried both using the UTF-8 setting in the URL request, as you may see, and the now commented piece under the NSLog.
The NSLog reports the correct cyrillic characters I made tests with.

Still when I print the value of the Message string at the beginning of the php script (insert.php) it has question marks instead.
If I manually write the cyrillic test in the php, it is correctly handled and even inserted in the DB as such.

What should I change in the protocol to have UTF-8 characters pass through correctly?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

There are many components at work here:

1. text input
2. app internal handling
3. transport over HTTP
4. output to browser
5. **browser displaying characters**

If the text is encoded in UTF-8 when it's input and none of steps 2 - 4 alter the raw string in any way, you should always be dealing with Unicode. The problem is *likely* that your browser does not know this and is trying to interpret the text as something else. Tell the browser it's dealing with UTF-8 text by setting an appropriate header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Actually I was aware the problem could be anywhere. For that reason I printed the value just before been passed to the NSURLRequest by NSLog and again at the beginning of the php script with an echo direction. As said the first print gives the cyrillic characters, while the echo question marks.

Comment: And as I said, this may simply be due to the *browser* (or wherever else you're outputting it) just displaying them wrong. It's unlikely that the encoding screwed up during *transport*, but the ultimate pitfall is always the actual *output*. Have you ruled this possibility out?

Comment: Yes, just in case I added the header direction before the echo but this is the feedback I catch on the ReceivedData: 2011-05-24 10:49:46.561 Virtual Tags[10268:707] I am beginning the parsing of: header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8')messaggio=????зшззщ<ok>Done</ok> : the russian text was manually entered in the php script and, as you may see, displays correctly: this is the php snippet that generates the output: $message=htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_MESSAGE'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo "header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8')";
echo "messaggio=".$message;
echo "зшззщ";

Comment: @Fabrizio Don't `echo "header(…)"`, just call `header(…)` as written above, otherwise there's no point. Just try `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); echo $_SERVER['HTTP_MESSAGE'];`.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes when I do that, but for the disappearance of the header direction in the feedback: 2011-05-24 14:17:37.798 Virtual Tags[10559:707] ho caricato fino a: 
2011-05-24 14:17:37.803 Virtual Tags[10559:707] sto iniziando il parsing di: messaggio=????зшззщ<ok>Done</ok>

Comment: Then I give up on the PHP side. :)

Comment: In fact the problem is in the protocol...!

Comment: Not really the *protocol*, just the way you're packing the data into the HTTP request. Apparently somewhere along the way it's transcoded to some other character set.

Comment: SO I got independently.. but given there is nothing between the URLConnection and the php script i wonder who transforms the text into question marks...